# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module for Axios in MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, github-actions, mern

I am trying to deploy a MERN stack-based app in azure through GitHub.

when the building is working in GitHub repo actions, getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      3 |
      4 | import "./chatbot.css";
    > 5 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
```

I have imported axios in multiple files and I believe the issue is with all such files. I have been working with react for sometime but it never was a problem (though I never tried hosting with azure Web App before).

In package.json I have also added:

`"type": "module"`

But the problem still persists.

The funny thing is, that the app can be built and run successfully locally.

I am expecting that the code is deployed perfectly in Azure through Github with the axios call as it is.

Because it runs perfectly locally.